# How to have a sound play while a color is clicked on a drawing application?

Tags: javascript, audio, drawing

I have currently created a simple drawing application and was wondering if anybody could help me with the coding of attaching a specific sound with a color and for every time a user is drawing on the canvas with the color the sound will play while drawing.

Thanks!

This is the Javascript I have so far for the drawing app:

```
var started = false;
var canvas, context;
var stampId = '';
var lastColor = 'red';
var lastStampId = '';

function init() {
    canvas = $('#imageView').get(0);
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Auto-adjust canvas size to fit window.
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth - 80 ;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 80 ;

    //$('#container').get(0).addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);

    // Add events for toolbar buttons.
    $('#red').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#orange').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#yellow').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#green').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#blue').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#purple').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id); }, false);


    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.

  }

  // The pencil tool instance.
  tool = new tool_pencil();
  // This painting tool works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
  // movements.
  function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
    // This starts the pencil drawing.
    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only 
    // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down 
    // the mouse button).
    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;
      }
    };

    // This is called when you release the mouse button.
    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  }

  // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
  // position relative to the canvas element.
  function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX ==0) { // Firefox
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 10 ) { // Opera
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }



function onClick(e) {
    if (stampId.length > 0) {
        context.drawImage($(stampId).get(0), e.pageX - 90, e.pageY - 60, 80, 80);
    }
}

function onColorClick(color) {
    // Start a new path to begin drawing in a new color.
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();

    // Select the new color.
    context.strokeStyle = color;

    // Highlight selected color.
    var borderColor = 'white';
    if (color == 'white' || color == 'yellow') {
        borderColor = 'black';
    }

    $('#' + lastColor).css("border", "0px dashed white");
    $('#' + color).css("border", "1px dashed " + borderColor);

    // Store color so we can un-highlight it next time around.
    lastColor = color;
}

function onFill() {
    // Start a new path to begin drawing in a new color.
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();

    context.fillStyle = context.strokeStyle;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function onStamp(id) {
    // Update the stamp image.
    stampId = '#' + id;

    $(lastStampId).css("border", "0px dashed white");
    $(stampId).css("border", "1px dashed black");

    // Store stamp so we can un-highlight it next time around.
    lastStampId = stampId;  
}
```

Comment: show example or what you have

Comment: seem my working examples below. Next time please add your full code, it had some bugs, partially because you added part of my code (and I didn't know you don't have the latest jquery), and partially because you didn't add my latest code... Don't forget to accept it, I debugged it for an hour...

Comment: Thank you so much! I just accepted it. All the best to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<audio id="snd_red" src="red.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="snd_blue" src="blue.mp3"></audio>
...

snd = null;
playing = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    if (snd && !playing) {
        playing = true;
        snd.play();
    }
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    if (snd && playing) {
        snd.stop();
        snd = null;
        playing = false;
    }
}, false);

function onColorClick(e, color){
    snd = document.getElementById("snd_" + color);
}
```

and you can do this in 1 line for all colors:

```
$('#red,#blue,#green,...').bind('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id, $(this).attr("id")); }, false);
```

but could be even:

```
$('.color').bind('click', function(e) { onColorClick(e.target.id, $(this).attr("id")); }, false);
```

if you could add class="color" to each one of them (but leave the is untouched)

SOLUTION:

basically my answer worked, but you're code had some problems:

http://neswork.com/javascript/sound-draw/1st/ (as you like: sound only when drowing)

http://neswork.com/javascript/sound-draw/2nd/ (as I like: sound always)

Comment: would I just use multiple ones of these for each different color?

Comment: Okay I got the sound to play but it plays when you click the color that appears on the sidebar, but I want the sound to play when you begin to draw with it, not just clicking the color. It also needs to stop when you stop drawing with it and stop and play the other sound only when that color is being used. Right now the sound just keep playing

Comment: I was tinkering with it but it still plays when I click on just the color on the side bar.

Comment: where can we see the example? or can you put it on jsfiddle.net? In my example you can see that in onColorClick I only select the color, and only when you "mousedown" on the canvas it starts to play. But it's hard to guess your environment. I supposed that the colors in the sidebar ar not on your canvas.

Comment: I put it on jsfiddle here is the link to it:http://jsfiddle.net/emv62192/TapSC/ , it obviously won't play the sound because right now the found files are only on my computer. I hope this helps you help me! Thanks so much you have been great!

Comment: that doesn't work. You can't just copy&paste your html like that. On the left go to "Add Resources" and add your javascripts (paint.js, init.js) [they have to be somewhere on the net for that to work) OR you can just add them in the javascript window. I added "alert(color);" to the 1st line of onColorClick. I can only help you when that'll work

Comment: Okay I am pretty sure I did that right and added all my resources onto it. Does that work?  http://jsfiddle.net/emv62192/NJceZ/